# How i match with best ratio of SequenceMatcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sequencematcher

I use the SequenceMatcher ratio to match two dataframe with the best ratio.

I want to check first if the score A and AA is good then check if the score between B is BB is good then if the score between C and CC is good, then I add the line

```
        A     B     C
0    pizza    ze    3
1    polo     fe    5
2    ninja    fi    NaN
```

```
     AA      BB      CC
0    za      ze      NaN
1    po      ka       8
2    fe      fe       6
3    pizza   fi       3
4    polo    ko       5
5    ninja   3        pizza
```

i want dataframe like this:

```
      A        B         C       AA          BB     CC      score
0    pizza    ze         3        pizza       ze      3      100
1    polo     fe         5        polo        ko      5       75
2    ninja    fi        NaN       ninja       3      pizza    30
```

I tried this function, but it doesn't work:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    return ratio
order = []
score = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    maxima = [similar(row['A'], j) for j in df2['AA']]
    best_ratio = max(maxima)
    if best_ratio > 0.9:     
        maxima2 = [similar(row['B'], j) for j in df2['BB']]
        best_ratio2 = max(maxima2)
        if best_ratio2 > 0.9:
           maxima3 = [similar(row['C'], j) for j in 
                      df2['CC']]
           best_ratio = max(maxima3)
           best_row = np.argmax(maxima3)
           order.append(best_row)
           score.append(best_ratio)

df2 = df2.iloc[order].reset_index()
merge = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to use tf idf to find the best ratio.